How can I use IFormFile in .Net 8.0 without deprecated packages
I just upgraded all of the projects in my solution from .Net6 to .Net8.
In all of the projects in the solution, I removed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features packages.  Then, in the projects that needed it, I added
<ItemGroup>
   <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

I have one project, though, that has a reference to IFormFile and that will not build unless I re-add the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features packages. These packages are both deprecated so I'm trying to remove the need for them.
Does IFormFile not exist in .Net 8 -- based on this it seems like it is part of .Net 8?  If not, what is the .Net 8 alternative?
P.S. The project in question does have the FrameworkReference listed above.

Can you please add a [mre]? IFormFile is part of the ASP.NET Core and adding FrameworkReference should be enough. Try building via command line (i.e. dotnet build from the project folder).

Why don't you add the package that is mentioned in the link you have provided? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref

They are part of the .Net8 framework after 2.2.2. So the independent package are deprecated. How you remove these packages in .net6? Does this project upgrade from more older version?

What is the Sdk set to in your project file? Our projects have it set to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web and we don't use a manual framework reference.

Revisited this today and it worked!  The only thing I can think of is that I accidentally removed the using or something.  I have no clue but everything worked this morning!  Thanks for all the input.

I had the same problem and I found the following description in the documentation:

With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no
longer published to NuGet as packages. Instead, the assemblies are
included in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App shared framework, which is
installed with the .NET Core SDK and runtime installers

So, the IFormFile interface declaration is already included to the platform. Using usual declaration should work:
public IActionResult Loading(IFormFile file)

The screenshot with the SDK version used in my project:


IFormFile remains in the same namespace, as it was since .NET Core 1. Adding fully qualified name/alias should be equivalent to adding using and should not have be exactly the same with or without the package.

@GuruStron: Accidentally, I named my project IFormFile. I known this is bad idea...

That is completely another problem and it will not be solved by adding the deprecated packages as OP's one is fixed.

@GuruStron: Thank you, I have removed not related part from the answer. And no need to use deprecated packages, when the framework is already contains the required interface definition.

"And no need to use deprecated packages" - yes, I know. But the point is that adding them to the solution which already has FrameworkReference fixes problem for OP.

You can see my note above, but it worked today.  What you described is exactly what I had tried yesterday -- today it worked.

@RHarris: Oh, I see. In such cases I'm trying to update the Visual Studio, remove bin/obj and then Rebuild Solution. Sometimes in not ordinary cases this helps.

I had this same problem.  I removed all the deprecated Nuget Packages for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.
Make sure the Project is .NET 8
Verify your Project SDK. (Right Click on Project and choose Edit Project File)
My Problem was it was referencing Microsoft.NET.Sdk instead of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web.  Once I changed it to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web, the references resolved after reloading the project.


 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>



